# Get data from url on my current page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data from url using javascript. From the previous page I sent the data using `$.redirect` . The code snipet is below.

First the page redirects to another page sending data

```
$.redirect("index.html", {"name":"zayne"});
```

The page redirects perfectly but i have no way of now getting this data on the current page i redirected to.

Comment: Does `$.redirect` add the values to the querystring? eg. yoursite.com?name=zayne

Comment: i doubt, i tried accessing the url using `window.location.href` and `document.url` , if you are using php you can access them through the `$_POST` method, but i want to know how to do it in js

Comment: If the values are sent through a POST request you cannot directly retrieve them from client-side JS

Comment: I marked two duplicates. The first covers the case where the `$.redirect` sends a POST request (which means you cannot access the values sent in client-side JS). The second covers the case where it sends a GET request and adds the values to the querystring.

Comment: Thank you, found the answer